# How to snap 2D cursor to key in graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

As the headline says: Is it possible to snap the 2D cursor in graph editor to a specific key? I can snap it in time from key to key using up and down arrow, but how can I exactly position the **horizontal** line to a key? I only found options to snap keys to the cursor, not the other way round.

[image: 2D cursor in graph editor]

Comment: You may use the *Down/Up Arrows* on your keyboard to jump between keyed frames.

Comment: As I wrote, this way you can just jump to the next key in timeline, but the 2D cursor then is positioned correct only vertically, not horizontally. The answer of cegaton is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Key>**Jump to keframe** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) to place the cursor on the selected keyframe.

[image]